# Regex to enforce alpha-numeric but allow apostrophes and hyphens?

Tags: php, regex

How would I alter this function so that it allows single apostrophe's and hyphens:

```
function sanitize_string($s) {
    $result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES));
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just include the single apostrophe and the hyphen at the end of the range:

```
function sanitize_string($s) {
    $result = preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9'-]+/", " ", html_entity_decode($s, ENT_QUOTES));
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: easy enough. Thanks for the help halfdan

Answer (score 2):

Trying  to get an answer to you as quick as I can.

I think you can just add them into the character class; possibly you'll need to escape them though.

Note: to use the `-` be sure to put it at the end otherwise it will be considered a meta character.